# Swagger UI 3.19.4 (Swagger 2.0) query parameter select

Tags: javascript, rest, swagger-ui

I have `Swagger UI 3.19.4` and I want to create `REST` requests like following:

```
GET https://<host>/<path>?select=*
```

It means that I want to add query parameter `select=*` in each get request that will be sent from `Swagger UI`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use `requestInterceptor`

```
SwaggerUiBundle({
...,
requestInterceptor: (request) => {
  uri = new URI(request.uri);
  uri.selectParams.append("select", "*");
  request.uri = uri.toString();
  //code
  return request;
}
})
```

I decided to use requestInterceptor, because it is official way to modify requests from SwaggerUI https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/.
Also to modify URL you can use standard class URL (JavaScript).

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.